# Will drinking room temperature water or drinking ice cold water hydrate you more effectively?

Tags: nutrition, hydration

I have heard that drinking room temperature water is easier for you body to absorb but I'm not sure if that is true or not.

Also, I am wondering, after a hard workout, will ice water hydrate you more effectively because it will also cool you down?

Comment: [Which Is Better, Drinking Ice Water or Warm Water?](http://www.livestrong.com/article/533835-which-is-better-drinking-ice-water-or-warm-water/)

Comment: As long as you are drinking water, and it's a temperature you can tolerate, it will hydrate you just the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any significant difference between both options.

That being said, cold water hydrates more effectively than room temperature. According to [this source](http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/better-drink-warm-rather-cold-water),

***During intense physical activity, the body's core temperature rises above the normal 98.6°F (37°C). Drinking cool water lowers the body's temperature and helps it settle back to its normal range. Studies have also shown that cold water 41°F (5°C) is absorbed more quickly from the stomach than warm, abating dehydration and allowing you to play harder and enjoy your game of soccer even more.***

[Another source](http://breakingmuscle.com/nutrition/cold-vs-room-temperature-water-during-workouts) conducted a study with participants drinking cold and room temperature water; the conclusion being

***The participants who had consumed the cold water during rest periods had a significantly smaller rise in core temperature compared to those who consumed the room temperature water.***

However, while cold water hydrates better, warm water relaxes the muscles better and makes it ready for more exercises:

***Subjects participating in the room temperature condition were able to perform significantly more bench press reps to failure than when they participated in the cold condition.***

So, cold water caused a slight performance hit, according to the study. Also, given that Olympic swimmers/divers shower in warm water before their races in order to prepare their muscles, I consider the study to be accurate.

That being said, I would still choose cold water over room temperature while exercising.